# activator or sbt start fails with Play 2.3

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.3

I was trying to launch the Play Framework 2.3.4 server on Windows 8 with `avtivator start` or `sbt start`, and run into following errors:

```
The input line is too long.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Because of the long CLASSPATH. But event with the newly created app I run into an error:

```
Bad application path: -Dhttp.port=9000
```

Answer (score 7):

The first problem can be solved [by adding](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/72) following lines to the `build.sbt`:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.Keys._

scriptClasspath := Seq("*")
```

The second problem is a [currently unresolved bug in sbt-native-packager](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3081) for Windows. The workaround for me was to use `sbt stage` and then launch directly the generated bat file at

```
\target\universal\stage\bin\
```

Answer (score 1):

well, I had the same problem about

```
Bad application path: -Dhttp.port=9009
```

So the way I solve it is by editing the Bat file. I manually add all the configuration parameters into the APP_MAIN_CLASS and before the "play.core.server.NettyServer"

something like:

```
set "APP_MAIN_CLASS= -DapplyEvolutions.default=true -Dhttp.port=9009 play.core.server.NettyServer"
```